# How to check if a string denotes a 24 hour valid time format using momentJS?

Tags: momentjs

The code:-

```
moment(moment("2022-12-12").format("YYYY-MM-DD"), "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isValid()
```

returns `true` as `2022-12-12` is a valid date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Using the same logic, I tried to check if `var timeString = "16:00:00"` is a valid time or not.

However, the following code:-

```
moment(moment("16:00:00").format("HH:mm:ss"), "HH:mm:ss", true).isValid()
```

always gives me `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's always giving true as you are formatting to that particular type first than checking if its valid which is why its always true.

I think you want something like this.

```
function isTimeFormat(time) {
    return moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss', true).isValid();
}
```